# Video loop on startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, video, operating-systems

I've setted up Rasp to start in Destktop mode and launch a video in loop mode.
The script, called by:

/etc/rc.local

is the seguent:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='omxplayer'
while true; do
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    :
else
    omxplayer -o hdmi /home/pi/movie.mov &
fi
done
```

The problem is that, on each video loop, run also an instance of dbus-daemon

```
dbus-daemon --fork --print-address 5 --print-pid 6 --session
```

In this way Rasp could crash.

What can I do to resolve this problem? Why is there this behaviour?

Comment: there's "add comment" button if you want to ask for a clarification or just comment

Comment: sorry I've just wrong button!

Comment: no problem, mistakes are easy to make =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, check how you call your loop script from `/etc/rc.local`, for example if your script is called `omx-loop` it should be called as `omx-loop &`, so the `/etc/rc.local` can continue execution until the end.

second, if it still does not work, try python solution (not mine):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

while True :
    subprocess.call( [ 'omxplayer', '/home/pi/movie.mov' ] )
```

This definitely should not call any `dbus-daemon`, just don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x omx-loop.py`.

Or there's more advanced "seamless" player in python available [here](http://www.sundh.com/blog/2013/10/loop-videos-seamlessly-omxplayer/).